# iPhone, where my sqlite db on my mac?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've added a function so that my database resides on the device, however, in the simulator I can't find it on my mac at all. It used to be in `Machintosh HD` before I used my function.

```
+ (NSString*)getDBPath {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bc.db"];
return dbPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be stored at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SDK>/Applications/<UUID>/Documents/bc.db
```

The **<SDK>** is a directory that represents the version of the simulator you are running. So, for instance, if you run it in the 4.1 simulator, replace **<SDK>** with **4.1**.

The **UUID** is generated by the simulator and will be different for each time you *install* the app (i.e., hit the "Run" button in Xcode). To discover which app is the one you're working on, just enter the various directories and look at name of the application bundle.